# How to display alert pop up for inserted record Id and redirect the VF page to another VF page

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, popup, onclick

I have a custom VF page 'HOMEPAGECOMMUNITY'. I would like to Navigate to 'LANDINGCOMMUNITY'.

I have a commandButton 'Submit' which is associated with couple of Rerender Id's for PageErrorMessages and PageBlock Section. (I hope this isnt the problem). 
The thing here is, I split my ACTION attribute of CommandButton into 2 parts with 'OnClick' and 'OnComplete' JS. 
Under 'Onclick' js -> I code my Controller SAVE() method with a redirection to 'LANDINGCOMMUNITY' Page. 
and under 'OnComplete' js -> I have my JS for poping out my ALERT MESSAGE.

Here my issue is , When i RETURN NULL for SAVE() method. Alert is popping up and also the record is saved. 
But i want to redirect to the 'LANDINGCOMMUNITY' page after i pop up an alert.
The base page should carry out the insertion of record from its controller and also pop up and redirect to NEW CUSTOM PAGE. 
Is this possible ? Please assist..

HERE IS MY CODE:

VF PAGE :

```
<apex:page controller="HomeController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"> 
    <apex:form >

    <apex:outputPanel id="jspanel"> 
        <script>  
        function onSaveReturn() {
            alert('{!message}');
        }
        </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:actionFunction name="doControllerSave" action="{!save}" rerender="jspanel"/> 

        <apex:pageBlock id="mainsection" mode="Edit">
            <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
            <br/>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!gotohome}" value="Go To Home"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!PreviousPage}" value="Previous" reRender="mainsection" rendered="{! If(level  != 1 ,true,false) }"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!NextPage}" value="Next" reRender="mainsection" rendered="{!IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(LstSSA)),LstSSA.size > 0), true, false) }"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="Submit();" oncomplete="onSaveReturn()" value="Submit" reRender="mainsection,msgs,jspanel" /> 
                <apex:commandButton onclick="saveDraft();" oncomplete="onSaveReturn()" value="Save as Draft" reRender="mainsection,msgs,jspanel" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
<!-- declaring a InputText field and a Long text area field here -->
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class HomeController
{  
public String message {get;set;}
public Integer level {get{return intLevel;} set;} 
public Boolean display;
public String longTextArea{get;set;}
public String caseSubject{get;set;}
public String IdSSA {get; set;}
public String message {get;set;}

public HomeController()
{
         ContactSelect = false; 
         message =' ';

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> sObjectMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
         Schema.SObjectType s = sObjectMap.get('Case') ;
         Schema.DescribeSObjectResult resSchema = s.getDescribe() ; 
         Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeInfo = resSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName(); 
         rtId = recordTypeInfo.get('some record type name').getRecordTypeId();
    getLstSSA();
    }

     public List<Service_Selection_Assistant__c> getLstSSA()
        {
        // some other function codes here 
    }

    public PageReference saveDraft()
    {
        caseStatus = 'Draft';
        return save();
    }

    public PageReference Submit()
    {
        caseStatus = 'Submitted';
        return save();
    }
    public PageReference save()
    {
        if(String.isBlank(caseSubject) || String.isBlank(longTextArea)){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Please fill Subject and Description'));
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            //saveSelectedOptions();
            Case mc = New Case();
        // some field values are retrieved from URL and apex Param - working fine 
            mc.id = caseId;
            mc.Status = caseStatus;
            mc.Priority = 'P3';
            mc.Origin = 'Community Portal';
            mc.Subject = caseSubject;
            mc.Description = longTextArea;
            mc.AccountId = orgIdSave;//orgIdSave retrieved from URL
            //mc.RecordTypeId = mapCaseRecordType.get(mapCST.get('CI Member Request').Record_Types__c).RecordTypeId;
            mc.RecordTypeId = rtId;
            Upsert mc;


            // to display an alert message after saving: 
            /*
            if(mc.Status == 'Submitted'){
            message += '';
            message += 'A Case has been Created. Your ticket Number is '+mc.CaseNumber+'.You will receive an email shortly';
            }
            else if(mc.Status == 'Draft'){
            message += '';
            message += 'Your Draft with Subject '+mc.Subject+'will be auto-deleted on '+mc.CreatedDate.addDays(180);
            }
            */

        // My issue with this redirect after Onclick and OnComplete
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + mc.id); //(OR) redirect to 'LANDINGCOMMUNITY'  page
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);           
            return pageRef;

        //return null; // --> this return Null gives me a pop up of my String 'message'. but remains on the same page, no redirection happens
    }
     }

}
```

`